Как разместить TextView в конце LinearLayout?
Мне нужно прикрепить один из TextView в конец Layout, чтобы было ровно так, как на скриншоте:

Так же хотелось бы узнать, как сделать линии между элементами (layout_gravity, gravity не работает).
Вот код:
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="#E1EBF0"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/frameLayout">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/day"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/inter_medium"
        android:text="10"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/month"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/inter_medium"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="8dp"
        android:text="10"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/year"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/inter_medium"
        android:text="10"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"/>
</LinearLayout>


Если вы имеете ввиду, чтобы TextView разделили всю ширину контейнера в равных пропорциях, то задайте им ширину в 0dp и одинаковые веса (layout_weight):
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="#E1EBF0"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/frameLayout">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/day"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fontFamily="@font/inter_medium"
        android:text="10"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/month"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fontFamily="@font/inter_medium"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="8dp"
        android:text="10"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/year"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fontFamily="@font/inter_medium"
        android:text="10"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"/>
</LinearLayout>

Разделитель в LinearLayout называется divider и настраивается атрибутами, содержащими это название:
android:showDividers="middle" - как отображать разделители
android:divider="?android:listDivider" - задать сам разделитель (цвет или изображение) 
android:dividerPadding="5dp" - отступ разделителя от края контейнера

